# Update Parent and Insert Child Telerik Opn Access with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper, telerik-open-access

I am using Telerik Open Access for database operation. I have a Parent Class named Order and it includes 2 classes named OrderHistory and Tasks. Now any kind of event happen like if order is put on hold or put for dispatching it's related entry will be put on OrderHistory table and Order table will be updated. Now I have done following code but it works sometimes but sometimes not. I don't know much about this telerik open access and automapper.

controller call:

```
OrderDTO updateorder = orderManagement.GetOrdersByOrderId(2);
updateorder.QueueId = 3;
updateorder.IsLocked = false;
updateorder.UpdatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
updateorder.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
OrderHistoryDTO alertDto = new OrderHistoryDTO()
{
    Event = 'Putting On Hold',
    OrderID = orderDTO.Id
    UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
    OccuerdDate = DateTime.Now,
    EventType = 'Event'
};
updateorder.OrderHistories.Clear();
updateorder.OrderHistories.Add(alertDto);
updateorder = orderManagement.UpdateOrder(updateorder);
```

db operations

```
public OrderDTO UpdateOrder(OrderDTO orderEntity)
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Tasks, m => m.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.OrderHistories, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.OrderHistories));
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<OrderHistoryDTO, OrderHistory>();    
    var orderBase = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Order>(orderEntity);  // It will sometimes make OrderHistories list count to 0. though in starting orderEntity has OrderHistories count = 1.
    base.Update(orderBase);
    base.Save();
    orderEntity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<OrderDTO>(orderBase);
    return orderEntity;
}
```

OrderDTO

```
public class OrderDTO
{
  public int OrderID { get; set; }
  public bool? IsLocked { get; set; }
  public int QueueId { get; set; }
  [ScriptIgnore]
  private IList<OrderHistoryDTO> _orderHistories = new   List<OrderHistoryDTO>();
  [ScriptIgnore]
  public virtual IList<OrderHistoryDTO> OrderHistories
  {
   get { return this._orderHistories; }
  }
  public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
  public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

OrderHistoryDTO

```
public class OrderHistoryDTO
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int UserID { get; set; }
  public int OrderID { get; set; }
  public string Event { get; set; }
  public string EventType { get; set; }
  public DateTime? OccuerdDate { get; set; }
  public UserDTO User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `it works sometimes but sometimes not` - What do you mean?

Comment: @rhughes sometimes 'ar orderBase = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Order>(orderEntity);' line make orderhistories list to 0 though there is a data.

Comment: @Dhwani, I tested your code with some random data in my database and did not reproduce the issue you describe. In case you find the problem related to Telerik Data Access (previously known as Telerik OpenAccess ORM), I would suggest to you to post your question in this forum: http://www.telerik.com/forums/data-access/general-discussions

Comment: @DoroteyaAgayna ok. I am still facing same issue. So I think now I have to put on forum. Thanks